# Correct way to retrieve collection using XPath?

Tags: java, xml

I've got an xml file of several recordings that looks like this:

```
<audiolibrary>
    <prompt name="accountinfo">
        <prompt-segment>
            <audio src="audio/default/accountinfo.wav" 
                text="Account Information"/>
        </prompt-segment>
    </prompt>
    ...
    <prompt name="accountclosed">
        <prompt-segment>
            <audio src="audio/default/accountclosed.wav"
                text="Sorry, your account is closed."/>
        </prompt-segment>
    </prompt>
</audiolibrary>
```

Following an XPath tutorial, I know I can retrieve, for example, the attribute of the first prompt with the following expressions:

```
xPathObject.compile("/audioibrary/prompt[@name='accountinfo']/prompt-segment/audiofile/@src");
xPathObject.compile("/audioibrary/prompt[1]/prompt-segment/audiofile/@src");
```

Now, if I want to retrieve all of the prompts, am I understanding correctly that I should iterate through .compile() statements until I come up with a blank value?

Something like this skeletal example, here?:

```
int index = 1;
do
{
    xPathObject.compile("/audioibrary/prompt["+ index +"]/prompt-segment/audiofile/@src");
    (Prompt content retrieval code here)
    index++;
}
while(!src.equals(""))
```

Or, is there a better way to retrieve the collection?

Thanks!
IVR Avenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit XPath, a little bit Recursion:

```
String basePromptExpression = "/AudioLibrary/prompt";

NodeList nodes  = (NodeList) xPathObject.evaluate(basePromptExpression, promptInputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < nodes.getLength(); nodeIndex++)
{
    Node singleNode = nodes.item(nodeIndex);
    String promptName = singleNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
    String promptSrc = findNode(singleNode, "audiofile").getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue();
    String promptText = findNode(singleNode, "audiofile").getAttributes().getNamedItem("text").getNodeValue();

    System.out.println("Name: "+promptName+" Src: "+promptSrc+" Text: "+promptText);
}


private static Node findNode(Node singleNode, String nodeName)
{
    Node namedNode=null;
    NodeList nodeChildren = singleNode.getChildNodes();
    Node childNode = null;

    for (int nodeIndex =0; nodeIndex < nodeChildren.getLength(); nodeIndex++)
    {
        childNode = nodeChildren.item(nodeIndex);

        if (childNode.hasChildNodes())
        {
            childNode = findNode(childNode, nodeName);
        }

        if (childNode.getNodeName().equals(nodeName))
        {
            namedNode = childNode;
            return namedNode;
        }
    }

    return namedNode;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
XPathExpression expr = xPathObject.compile("/audiolibrary/promp/prompt-segment/audio/@src")
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    //what you are going to do.... 
}
```

Comment: And if I want to retrieve all of the attributes (name, src, and text)?

Comment: Then you query for `/audiolibrary/promp/prompt-segment/audio`, and get the attributes you like from it, or you use `/audiolibrary/promp/prompt-segment/audio/@*`

Comment: So, if I want all three in a single "Prompt" object, I'd make a collection (such as an arraylist) for each type, fill the collections, and then empty them into a single collection of Prompts?

Comment: Erm, I don't know your _Prompt_ object, and I'm not that well versed in Java, so I don't know exactly what you mean with 'empty them into a single collection', but suffice to say, if you go for an XPath selecting prompts, you can get either named attributes as Strings with `getAttribute`, or them all in a list of Attrs in a NamedNodeMap with `getAttributes`. I don't see why you'd make a list per type if you're just going to end up assiging them to different objects later on...

Comment: Sounds like you're really interested in unmarshalling XML, you may be interested in XStream, JAXB, JiBX or other similar libraries.

Comment: If you are interested in XPath based XML unmarshalling check out MOXy JAXB:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html